# OneDrive API scopes

Tags: onedrive

I have an application that used SkyDrive API. After SkyDrive was replaced I upgraded my code to use OneDrive API.

Looking my application in the dev page (https://account.live.com/consent/Manage) I could notice that the scopes I used with SkyDrive ("wl.offline_access", "wl.signin", "wl.basic", "wl.skydrive", "wl.skydrive_update") and the scopes I used with OneDrive ("onedrive.readwrite", "onedrive.appfolder", "wl.offline_access") were there.

Everything was working until last month, even with all these scopes. But now I'm not being able to upload files. I'm receiving a Bad Request error (Code 400).

I discovered that adding the ""onedrive.readonly" scope fix the upload but I don't know why. I also know that an application with only the OneDrive scopes ("onedrive.readwrite", "onedrive.appfolder", "wl.offline_access") also works.

Does anybody knows what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the oAuth token has Files.ReadWrite capability using 
http://jwt.calebb.net/.

If not present, when you are logging in the user, give the scope while obtaining code as

> files.readwrite.all offline_access